# Can I use phantom power on an iPad?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, ipad, garageband, phantom

Is there a way to connect both phantom power and an iPad mini to my computer, so that I can use a condenser microphone in GarageBand? The microphone is an [Earamble BM-800](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N9OF9C8) and the phantom power is [Neewer 1-Channel 48V Phantom Power Supply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014H8AWGC). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most laptops have only one input (usually for microphones, not line-in) nowadays, it would be safer to have an 2 channel usb or firewire interface. It should have phantom powered inputs anyways so you don't have to bother with external ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I just need to stop being cheap and get something I'm going to use :)